# Fill drop down box with values from a class

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, html-select

i have this as JSP page and i want a combobox to fill up the values from a table in the database.
I have a class Assembly and a Class Assemblys, in Assemblys i make every record an instance of Assembly and put it in a list. But i can't retrieve it in JSTL? Why is this?

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
 .....
 <select name = "assembly">
 <c:forEach var ="item" items="${Assemblys}">
 <option value="${item.id}">${item.Name}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

This as the class Assembly Class

```
 public class Assembly {
 public String Name;
 public int cost;
 public int id;

 public Assembly(String Name, int cost, int id) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.id = id;
 }
}
```

And this is the class Assemblys

```
 public class Assemblys {
  List<Assembly> list = new ArrayList<Assembly>();
  public Assemblys(){

  list = getAssemblys();
         }

  private List<Assembly> getAssemblys() {

    try {
        Connection conn = MysqlConnect.conn();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String Query = "Select * from tbl_assembly";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
           rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
          Assembly ass = new Assembly(rs.getString(2),rs.getInt(3),rs.getInt(1));
           list.add(ass);
         }
         conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assemblys.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    return list;
    }
}
```

Why is my drop down list blank? I don't get it.
I thought this was the right code?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In which attribute, you are setting Assemblys in servlet. Please paste the code of servlet...

Comment: There is no servlet, this is not required for this code to work(atleast I thought so)

Comment: How did you invoke  getAssemblys method of Assemblys class

Comment: because it's in the constructor it gets runned when i initiate the class Assemblys? no?

Comment: Who called the Assemblys constructor

Comment: this code: <c:forEach var ="item" items="${Assemblys.list}"> ?

Comment: It will not invoke constructor of Assemblys. Please read my answer..
For reference : http://www.shaunabram.com/helloworld-jsp-servlet/

Comment: well i shall do it that way, but i'm sure that there is a way to do it without a preprocessing servlet :(

thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a servlet or using scriptlet(marked as bad practice) in jsp to invoke class Assemblys. The tag you specified, i am guessing that you are using servlet/jsp application.

The name Assemblys used in jsp should be in request object as attributes. The key you specify for Assemblys can be used for fetch the list.

Answer (score 1):

First you should add getters to Assembly class.

```
public class Assembly {
 public String Name;
 public int cost;
 public int id;

 public String getName() {
  return this.Name;
 } 

 public int getId() {
   return this.id;
 }

 public Assembly(String Name, int cost, int id) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.id = id;
 }
}
```

Second add getList method to Assemblys

```
public class Assemblys {
  List<Assembly> list = new ArrayList<Assembly>();

  public List<Assembly> getList() {
        return this.list;
  } 

  public Assemblys(){

  list = getAssemblys();
         }

  private List<Assembly> getAssemblys() {

    try {
        Connection conn = MysqlConnect.conn();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String Query = "Select * from tbl_assembly";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
           rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
          Assembly ass = new Assembly(rs.getString(2),rs.getInt(3),rs.getInt(1));
           list.add(ass);
         }
         conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assemblys.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    return list;
    }
}
```

And now jsp

```
 <select name = "assembly">
 <c:forEach var ="item" items="${Assemblys.list}">
 <option value="${item.id}">${item.Name}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Comment: oow yeah, forgot the getters indeed. But it still doesn't work :S

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<c:forEach var ="item" items="${Assemblys}">
```

with

```
<c:forEach var ="item" items="${Assemblys.list}">
```

**EDIT :**

Combining @user2006574 and @AntonIlinchik answers, you have to add the getters to Assembly, change the getter in Assemblys to public access.

Also, post the code where the `Assemblys` constructor is called.